# Url.Action only render controller and action but not id

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to render a URL for a JavaScript search that I am doing. Unfortunately `Url.Action` renders not only the action but the current id. This occurs when presently on page utilizing the action with the id.

To illustrate `Url.Action("List", "Org");` will first render `Org/List` from which I can append an org to be listed. However, after the location has been moved to `Org/List/12345` `Url.Action("List", "Org");` will render `Org/List/12345` and appending to that creates an issue where I end up with `Org/List/12345/6789`.

Is there a different method I can use other than `Url.Action`? I've thought about using JavaScript to check for the number of `/` and removing part of the string but that seems a bit hackish.

```
// appears in my Site.Master & utilizes the AutoComplete plugin for jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#FindOrg").autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("Find", "Org") %>', {
        minChars: 3,
        maxItemsToShow: 25
    }).result(function(evt, data, formatted) {
        var url = '<%= Url.Action("List", "Org") %>/';
        window.location.href = url + data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:

What happens if you use `Url.Action("Find", "Org", new { id = "" })`?

Alternately, try manually building the url with `Url.Content("~/Find/Org")`.

Comment: `Url.Action("Find", "Org", new { id = "" })` did the trick. Should have been so very obvious!

Comment: Nice.  Hadn't tried it myself so I wasn't sure, but it does use Routing internally, so I thought it might override whatever behavior was causing it to grab the current id.

Answer (score 0):

You could 'cheat' and access the 'Controller' and 'Action' entries in the Routing Dictionary. This would then allow you to construct only the part of the url you need. The only caveat is that if you change your routing model these routines may become incorrect.