# ASP.NET MVC Routing and URL.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

in one of my asp.net mvc 2 views I am have the following statement

```
window.location.href = '<% = Url.Action("Index","Feature", new {id=""}) %>/' + $("#ProductId").val();
```

as can be seen $("#ProductId").val() can only be computed from client action and so outside url.Action

I have my Routes as shown below:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allimages}", new {allimages = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?"});
           routes.MapRoute(
              "Default", // Route name
              "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
          );


           routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultIndex", // Route name
            "{controller}.mvc/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
        );
            routes.MapRoute("Root", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });


        }
```

The request with Url.Action fails because the route thinks the "action" is the "id"
[image]

How can I make sure the route configuration in "DefaultIndex" is validated  and the url is

**Key   >>           Value

controller =      Feature

action   =           index

id   =           9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a**

**Edit 2**

Image 2:

[image]

**Edit 1- Route Order**

I almost thought I solved it by changing the route order

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultIndex", // Route name
            "{controller}.mvc/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );



           routes.MapRoute(
              "Default", // Route name
              "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
          );



            routes.MapRoute("Root", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

it did work for 
http://localhost:61000/Feature.mvc/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a/

but failed for a post on same page

http://localhost:61000/Product.mvc/List

**** History ****

Have been using  + $("#ProductId").val();
="/domainname[virtual directory alias]/Fewature.mvc/Index"+$("#ProductId").val();

always worked, though I had to change all scripts when posted to server domainname[virtual directory alias]/ changes from development to test to production

trying to streamline it:

Had the following statement earlier:

window.location.href = '<% = Url.Action("Index","Feature"}) %>/' + $("#ProductId").val();

Would result in multiple Id values

http://localhost:61000/Feature.mvc/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a/3c5941e4-cb25-4d6f-9117-9ed100b4ca91

it maps existing route {id} into  Url.Action("Index","Feature"}

resulting in NoMatch

Introduced

**new {id=""}**   to get around it.

Comment: -- Came up with a hack but I dont want to use it--  Idea is to introduce a "/" and then Url.Action renders action ("index")window.location.href = '<% = Url.Action("Index","Feature", new {id="/"}) %>' + $("#ProductId").val();

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Url.RouteUrl instead

```
window.location.href = '<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { @Controller = "Feature", @Action = "Index"}) %>/' + $("#ProductId").val();
```

Comment: the problem with double ids in this case-- http://localhost:61000/Feature.mvc/Index/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a   when I try to search the same id again

Comment: it seems to have truncated the url. here it is again Feature.mvc/Index/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a

Comment: can you check the value from $("#ProductId").val()? The Url.RouteUrl part shouldn't generate the link with id.

Comment: it does. It is I think a feature of ASP.NET MVC routing. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734679/url-actionaction-controller-routevalues-doubling-up-id-in-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088605/url-action-only-render-controller-and-action-but-not-id

Comment: can you post me what '<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "Index", Action = "Feature"}) %>/' renders?

Comment: Oops my bad... should be  '<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "Feature", Action = "Index"}) %>/'

Comment: I did correct it , forgot to mention it earlier.  Check Edit 2 in my question above it shows rendering for both URL.Action and Url.RouteUrl

Answer (score 1):

Your routing is all messed up. What's the reason for the second route: `{controller}.mvc/{id}` ... ? It's clashing with the first route.

If a URL like `/mycontroller/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a` comes in the routing engine will always route it to `{controller}/{action}/{id}` because it's first in the list and the url can be mapped to that route, i.e. there are no route constraints and id is optional.

If I was you, I would just remove the second route... if you really need the second route then move it above the first route and then put a route constraint on it.

Comment: @Charlino- I tried moving the 2nd route to the top. It worked as I said in my edit 1 but somehow my JQGrids post started to fail.  On the constraints , is it possible that if url is like /mycontroller/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a   and the last part conforms to Guid to have it mapped to {Id} and have action defaulted to "Index"

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But you're making things hard for yourself... why don't you just stick with the one route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`?

Comment: @Charlino- I would like to. but <% = Url.Action("Index","Feature", new {id=""}) %>/' + $("#ProductId").val();
evaluates to Feature.mvc/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a  >> Routing  takes action =id

Comment: @charlino- checkout Image 2 under Edit 2 in my question. If I make use of default routing, url.Action evaluates to Feature.mvc/Feature.mvc/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a. if it had the index, the url will work. anyway to force Index to show up in Url.Action if {id} is empty or null